# Send message to content script that lives outside of a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

Here's my setup; I have my browser action pull up popup.html which runs my main script. I also have a background.html running in the background which in it has an iframe. I have a content script that runs in the page I pull into the iframe. Picture for clarity:

[image]

I need to be able to send a message from main_script.js to content_script.js. This is usually done with something like chrome.tabs.sendMessage which requires a tab id along with every other method I've found for message passing TO a content script FROM a script elsewhere. The thing is, with this setup, my content script doesn't have a tab id for me to use to send it a message.

Is there some other way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Have you tried having the content_script open a [persistent connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) to a script running in background.html that proxies messages from the popup?

Comment: I currently have a persistent connection setup in this direction. It doesn't suit my purposes as I need a button click in the popup to send a message to the content script. Any attempt I've made to try and use the port for anything other than just responding to messages from the background has failed with undefined errors or use of expired port errors.

Comment: Your background page should maintain the port open, and your popup use the background page as a proxy.

Comment: @Xan Can you elaborate? Even if I have a script in the background page, it can't send messages to the content script without needing a tab id just like when trying to send a message from the main script.